# Use unregister_chrdev_region in case registration failed

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am learning how to write kernel drivers, and I have a doubt about the proper 
usage of the function unregister_chrdev_region.

Right now I have a simple test module with just the init and 
exit functions:

```
static dev_t devn; 

int __init my_dev_init(void)
{
    devn = MKDEV(0,0); 

    if(alloc_chrdev_region(&devn,0,1,"my_dev") != 0)
    {
        return -EBUSY; 
    }
    else
    {
        return 0; 
    }
}

void __exit my_dev_exit(void)
{
   unregister_chrdev_region(devn,1);  
 }
```

My question: is it safe to call unregister_chrdev_region if the registration failed ? I would assume no, but pretty much all example code that I have seen calls unregister_chrdev_region no matter what happened during the initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registration rarely fails. If registration fails, init function fails, thus insmod command will not succeed in loading the kernel module i.e. **test.ko** and device node will not be created. So there is no question of unregistration (rmmod). If registration is successful then only we can unregister the driver i.e. unloading the kernel, removal of device node etc... using rmmod. If in init function registration is successful and some other API fails then need to add goto statements, jump to appropriate goto label to unregister and return the appropriate error value. Hope I have cleared your doubt :-)